# Why are there empty indexes and what should I do with them?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've written a script which reorganizes/rebuilds indexes in SQL Server depending on their fragmentation.

Some Index are `NULL` or `whitespace` and I cannot reorganize or rebuild them. what are they, where do they come from and how should I handle them?

That's my code to get them:

```
$getFragQuery = "SELECT dbschemas.[name] as 'Schema',
                dbtables.[name] as 'Table',
                dbindexes.[name] as 'Index',
                indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
                indexstats.page_count
                FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
                INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
                INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
                INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
                AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
                WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()"

$FragRate = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $ConnectionString -Query $getFragQuery
```

Examples of empty index and named index:

```
Schema                       : dbo
Table                        : LizenzHandling
Index                        : PK_LizenzHandling
avg_fragmentation_in_percent : 0
page_count                   : 0

Schema                       : dbo
Table                        : ServiceFelder
Index                        : 
avg_fragmentation_in_percent : 83.3333333333333
page_count                   : 7
```

Edit: Just to clarify: I can just skip those empty indexes in my code, but I want to know what they are and where do they come from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that you can get `null` names is if you're looking at a table which is a heap (no clustered index). The heap itself will show up with a `null` name.

You can confirm if this is the case here by also including the `index_id` column from `sys.indexes`. Heaps show up with an `index_id` of 0.